# Chrome CSS Width Issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, render

Anyone seen this before?

Chrome for some reason has a slight width render issue that does not show up in Firefox or Safari.If you look at the image will see that with Chrome there is a slight vertical indent. The top and the current element are both at the same HTML DOM level. Both are have the same  &  relationship and CSS.

I'm using bootstrap and LESSHat. Don't think it is CSS as no problems with Firefox or Safari.

I attempted to antialias, grayscale, but none of it makes a difference. [image]

```
& div.toolbar-group {
position:                               absolute;
z-index:                                200;
width:                                  96%;
padding:                                0;
margin:                                 0 auto;
margin:                                 20% 0 0 2%; 
white-space:                            nowrap;
-webkit-font-smoothing:                 antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:                grayscale;      
background:                             #3c4145;
.box-shadow(    2px 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6), 
                -2px 0 0px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6));          
& ul.toolbar-frame {
    position:                           relative;
    list-style:                         none;
    height:                             38px;
    width:                              98%;
    border:                             1px solid #000; 
    .background-image(linear-gradient(to bottom, #525252 0%,#2b2b2b 100%)); 
}
```

}

Comment: Found a the answer. The div elements need to be on the same DOM level or Chrome can render differently. If I adjust so that toolbar and header are on the same level then Chrome renders fine.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome width is not what you get with javascript or CSS.

Try resizing with this code while Dev Tools open.
Needs jquery for ease

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        console.log(" -jqwidth:", $(window).width(), " -inner:", window.innerWidth, " -outer:", window.outerHeight );
 });
```

It outputs like:

```
-jqwidth: 973  -inner: 992  -outer: 1100
```

While Chrome shows **892**

Chrome is worst than Explorer nowadays. It just s.ucks.